# merge sheets based on two common columns

Tags: excel, join, merge

I have two sheets of data, containing origins, destinations and travel times.
Now, I would like to find the lowest value of both these sheets for each Origin-Destination (OD) combination.
However, my data is not perfect, so there are a few OD-combinations in sheet two that do not occur in sheet one.

This lead to me wanting to join/merge the two data sheets based on both the Origin *and* the Destination having the same value.

I added a screenshot of my data.

I would like my data to become:

Origin; Destination; minutes; Total minutes;

Obviously for the corresponding O's and D's

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you in advance

[Sample of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6tD7.png)

Comment: Okay, so there is a possibility to solve this easily.
I do however, not fully understand what you mean. Could you elaborate a little further please?

Thank you

Comment: If there's not data in entire column A: Add `=B1&"|"&C1` in cell A2 and fill it down till last row. Now put `=vlookup(I1&"|"&J2,A:D,4,0)` in cell L2 and fill it down till last row. Give title to L columm as Minutes.

Comment: It is working! Thanks a lot, the both of you